# My code is not deleting rows, rest all is working fine

Tags: excel, vba

I have complied the below code for creating a separate bank payment sheet, everything is working fine but it is not deleting the rows of the cells whose value is "Delete" in column "E".

i have also observed while debugging that sometimes it deletes and sometimes it don't.

but now it is not deleting at all.

where I'm going wrong?

```
Sub Create_Bank_Sheet()

Dim fname As String
Dim path As String
Dim varResponse As Variant

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

varResponse = MsgBox("Select 'Yes' or 'No' File will be Saved at  : " & Range("c43").Value, vbYesNo, "Are you sure you want to SaveAs this Sheet?")
If varResponse <> vbYes Then Exit Sub



Sheets("Bank Sheet for Payment").Select


path = Sheets("Command Center").Range("c43")

fname = Sheets("Command Center").Range("c42")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bank Sheet for Payment").Copy
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & "\" & fname, _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False



     Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False



Dim c As Range
Dim SrchRng As Range
Dim SrchStr As String

Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("e4", ActiveSheet.Range("e65536").End(xlUp))
SrchStr = "Delete"
Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find(SrchStr, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
Loop While Not c Is Nothing

ActiveWorkbook.Save

MsgBox ("File saved in " & path)



ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True





End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting your `SrchRng` correctly.

Try

```
Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("E4:E" & ActiveSheet.Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row)
```